# How to instantly update a smoothly updating progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bit of a specific question but I have a progress bar traveling from `100%` to `0%` over 10 seconds and I would like to, upon clicking a button, to jump it to whatever percent and continue from there. Here is a fiddle so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/41o6xvyt/

This *kinda* works except for the fact I have to use a timeout and some instant css switching trickery to get it to work (and even then it may not work on slower computers and it loses however many milliseconds). I was wondering if there was a better way that didn't require timeouts or this kind of hack in order to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you need the `setTimeout()` it is because the changes are cached by the browser and only applied after the entire script executes. The `setTimeout` allows one script to execute, then another after the timeout. This allows the CSS changes to be applied. In your example if we only call `b()` here is what's going on:

```
$("#first").css({ 'transition-duration' : '0s' });  // Cache change1
$("#first").css("width","50%");                     // Cache change2
$("#first").css({ 'transition-duration' : '5s' });  // Overwrite change1
$("#first").css("width", "0%");                     // Overwrite change2
// Apply style changes
```

The first changes to `transition-duration` and `width` practically never even existed, and never where applied since it was all done at the end of the script.

If you read the `offsetHeight` property of the element it will flush the cache and apply the changes, this will force the changes made to the CSS to be applied.

Also you will need to do is change the progress bars `width` to be set in CSS rather than as an attribute (*as the flush only affects the CSS and not the items directly in `style`*).

```
$("#report_jump").click(function(){
    $("#first").css({ 'transition-duration' : '0s' });
    $("#first").css("width","50%");
    $("#first")[0].offsetHeight; // flush CSS, the above changes will now be applied
    b();
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/41o6xvyt/1/)

---

***Note***

The *"instant css switching trickery"* isn't really trickery. We simply want to change the `width` to `50%` and do so in 0 seconds. That's why the `'transition-duration' : '0s'` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks this works great and the explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

you could try using keyframe
[http://jsfiddle.net/j44gbwna/3/](http://sample%20code)

```
@keyframes loader {
    0% {left: 0px;}
    99% { left: 100%;} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% {width: 0%;left:0;right:0}
    50% { width: 100%;left:0;right:0} 
    99% { width: 0%;left:100%;right:0} 
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further? I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your codes and found a solution

```
$("#report_start").click(function(){
     $("#first").removeClass('notransition');
     $("#first").css("width","0%");
});

$("#report_jump").click(function(){
    $("#first").css("width","50%");
    $("#first").addClass('notransition'); // to remove transition
    var dummyDelay=$("#first").width();   
   $("#report_start").trigger('click');
 });
```

And add class in css

```
.notransition { 
  -webkit-transition: none !important; 
  -moz-transition: none !important; 
  -o-transition: none !important; 
  -ms-transition: none !important; 
  transition: none !important; 
}
```

See live 
https://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/jbL3n4kj/